# table ci_session doesn't exist error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, ion-auth

I was trying to configure ion_auth in my codeigniter from [this](https://avenir.ro/authentication-system-with-ion-auth-and-ci3/lets-install-ion-auth-library/) link.As the initial step shown in the [tutorial](https://avenir.ro/authentication-system-with-ion-auth-and-ci3/lets-install-ion-auth-library/) and [codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) tutorial, I have set the seeion in config.php as below:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');
```

Created ci_session table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
 );
```

But when I load my codeigniter I get this error:

```
        A Database Error Occurred
    Error Number: 1146

    Table 'db_platform.ci_session' doesn't exist

    SELECT `data` FROM `ci_session` WHERE `id` = '957v38u8kf237dnsbq5f63345opank6t'

    Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/platform/system/database/DB_driver.php

    Line Number: 691
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. I am new to codeigniter session and ion_auth. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: In your CREATE TABLE syntax it's `ci_sessions` and in your error it's `ci_session`. You are missing `s` in table name.

Comment: @bhavin table name was the issue.. Its solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Typo in your Table Name because in create table syntax it's `ci_sessions`,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
```

And in the error it's showing error in table name `ci_session`,

```
SELECT `data` FROM `ci_session` WHERE `id` = '957v38u8kf237dnsbq5f63345opank6t'.
```

So, You are missing `s` in table name.